# Scrolling Event not working JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this div:

```
<div id="inbox-prof-load-msg" class="message-content row nice-scroll">                      
    <?php include_once('inbox-chat-msg.php'); ?>                            
</div>
```

And i'm trying to get the `Scroll()` of this div:

```
$('div#inbox-prof-load-msg').scroll(function() {
    console.log('Scrolled')
});
```

Why i'm not getting the Scroll event? I've made a `.click()` call to test, and the Javascript doesn't got the click event on the div too. 
Someone know how to fix it?

**NOTE :** The element `div#inbox-prof-load-msg` is added dynamically to the DOM.

Thanks.

Comment: which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Does `inbox-prof-load-msg` div added dynamically?

Comment: Does the element actually scroll?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj 1.11.0

Comment: *"I've made a .click() call to test, and the Javascript doesn't got the click event on the div too."* that is very much related to your problem. Have you considered the possibility of `$('div#inbox-prof-load-msg')` returning 0 elements?

Comment: @palaѕн Yes! Added dynamically

Comment: As @KevinB pointed out, please check the output of `console.log( $('div#inbox-prof-load-msg').length )`

Comment: How can this be added dynamically, if it has PHP code inside it?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj ajax

Comment: @KevinB Oh sorry, missed that. Yes, then event delegation is the way to go.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj console.log prints '1'

Comment: @GustavoHenrique I thought so. You will need to use event delegation then for it to work for elements dynamically added to the DOM. Also, since ID are supposed to be unique in DOM you can simply use `#inbox-prof-load-msg` instead of `div#inbox-prof-load-msg`

Comment: You will probably want to throttle or debounce the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** when you deal with fresh DOM (elements added dynamically to the DOM) :

```
$('#inbox-prof-load-msg').on('scroll',function (event) {
    console.log('Scrolled');
});

$('body').on('click', 'div#inbox-prof-load-msg', function() {
    console.log('Clicked')
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var div = "<div id='inbox-prof-load-msg'> test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br></div>";

$('body').append(div);

$('#inbox-prof-load-msg').on('scroll',function (event) {
  console.log('Scrolled');
});

$('body').on('click', '#inbox-prof-load-msg', function() {
  console.log('Clicked')
});
```

```css
#inbox-prof-load-msg{
  height:150px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, i'm trying the 'scroll' but isn't working, but the 'click' works, you know why?